# How to get the values seperated by comma in a single column using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I have the below table and expected result. Please let me know if it is possible to achieve the result. Please refer the picture attached.

[image]

Comment: The solution would be RDBMS specific. What do you use?

Comment: Yes please, Oracle RDBMS is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `listagg()`:

```
select e.id, e.name, e.sal,
       listagg(d.dept, ',') within group (order by d.dept_id) as depts,
       listagg(d.dept_id, ',') within group (order by d.dept_id) as dept_ids,
from employee e left join
     department d
     on e.name = d.name
group by e.id, e.name, e.sal;
```

Some comments on the data model.

- Your `department` table should have a `dept_id` that is the primary key (no duplicates).
- Your table that is called `department` should really be called `employee_departments` because it is a junction table, combining two different entities.
- This table should be using `emp_id` as the link to `employee`, not `name`.  That is, the foreign key relationship should be to the primary key of `employee`.

Comment: Yes, this works well for me. Thank you very much for the additional comments.

Comment: Hello Gordon,I am getting the error "String concatenation too long" message, while merging some columns. Can you please suggest a workaround for that also?

Comment: @rinsonjimmy . . . There really isn't a work-around (although you could use a CLOB, but those are hard to work with).  Oracle strings are limited to 4000 characters.  There are some tricks for truncating the values.  That would be more appropriate for another question.

Comment: @ Gordon, Very much appreciate your reply. Thank you for your quick response.